# Google Sheets IF OR AND Formula with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking for a formula to use in google sheets that creates a boolean when the conditions "House" and "Car" are both found in the other columns so

| Name | Priority | Priority | Priority | Boolean in question |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | House | Car | Loans |  |
| Ned | House | Groceries | Car |  |
| Dom | Family | Car | Going Fast |  |
| Thanos | Stones | Balance | House |  |
| Homer | Donuts | Car | House |  |

would become

| Name | Priority | Priority | Priority | Boolean in question |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | House | Car | Loans | Yes |
| Ned | House | Groceries | Car | Yes |
| Dom | Family | Car | Going Fast | No |
| Thanos | Stones | Balance | House | No |
| Homer | Donuts | Car | House | Yes |

How can I write a formula to create this outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Boolean-in-question column, paste this formula:

```
=IF(AND(OR(B2="House";C2="House";D2="House");OR(B2="Car";C2="Car";D2="Car"));"Yes";"No")
```

If you have any difficulty mixing IF AND and OR, you can create extra columns like this:

[image: easier solution]

IF operator:

[image: IF operator]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=INDEX(IF(MMULT(ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(B2:D6,"Car")+(REGEXMATCH(B2:D6,"House"))),{1;1;1})=2,"Yes","No"))
```

[image]

A slight modification if the search words in one row can be repeated:

```
=INDEX(IF(((MMULT(REGEXMATCH(B2:D6,"Car")*1,{1;1;1})>0)+(MMULT(REGEXMATCH(B2:D6,"House")*1,{1;1;1})>0))=2,"Yes","No"))
```

Comment: Thank you this did the trick, now ill just be spending the next 30 minutes figuring out why and how any of this works.